# json_encode(): Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument (php)

Tags: php, json, utf-8

I have list of player name. But the problem is the player name contains some non utf-8 characters. so i am having following error.

```
json_encode(): Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument
```

i have used following code to overcome it, but it didn't work.

```
utf8_encode($player->name);
```

and

```
$player_name = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($player->name, mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $player->name);
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give an example player name where the error occur?

Comment: this is the json working on the local pc. & it seems to have no problem. But on live server we encounter with the problem.{
  "player_id" : 125,
  "player_name" : "J\u00c3\u0083\u00c2\u00balio C\u00c3...",
  "player_country" : "35",
  "player_country_name" : "Brazil",
  "player_team" : "Brasil",
  "player_role" : "Goalkeeper",
  "player_price" : 0,
  "substitute" : 0,
  "captain" : 1,
  "vice_captain" : 0
 }

Comment: when it is rendered on the browser it displays JÃÂºlio CÃ

Comment: Yes i saw. Seems indeed broken. Maybe this library could help you https://github.com/neitanod/forceutf8 see also here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344692/i-need-help-fixing-broken-utf8-encoding

Comment: possible duplicate of [json\_encode(): Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205722/json-encode-invalid-utf-8-sequence-in-argument)

Answer (score 2):

Just had the same issue and was able to solve it by forcing UFT-8 with [mb_convert_encoding()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php):

```
$string = mb_convert_encoding($string,'UTF-8','UTF-8');
```